# How to count the number of connected shapes for $n$ cells on a hexagonal lattice?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-lattices, combinatorial-geometry

On a hexagonal lattice, we can always definitely say if two cells are adjacent or not. I call a set of $n$ marked cells a 'connected shape' if we can trace a path through all of them without going through some other cell.

Here is the picture representing possible connected shapes for $1,2,3,4$ cells:

[image]

> How do we compute a number of distinct connected shapes made from $n$ cells on a hexagonal lattice?

I marked red three shapes which have a 'twin' which can't be obtained by rotation. We can either count such shapes as two different shapes (one obtained from another by reflection) or as the same shape. It depends on what is more simple for large $n$.

---

I'm thinking to use hexagonal coordinates with constraints on the distances between them. We can take one cell as the origin. But this still gives too many equations for large $n$.

Comment: You forgot a $n=4$-shape: Take the "foot" of the red figure and move it directly up by one.

Comment: @Lovsovs, you are right, thanks. I'll correct it

Comment: Maybe http://oeis.org/A000228 will get you started.

Comment: There is no nice formula for polyominoes on square lattice; why would it be here?

Comment: Found another one: Take the lower red figure and move the upmost tile one "tick" to the left (giving a "snake-shape").

Comment: @GerryMyerson Doesn't that just outright answer the question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you. To tell the truth, I didn't know what polynominoes were (only dominoes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems no closed form formula for this problem can be found in the literature.

[Here](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~guttmann@unimelb/articles/hex12.pdf) is a paper in which the number of different possible connected configurations of $n$ hexagons (ignoring rotational symmetries) for $n\leq 35$ is listed (on p. 24).

[This OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000228) gives the same number for $n \leq 21$, but here taking symmetries into consideration.

---

*Note: The OIES-page was found by @Gerry Myerson - if he would like to answer, I will gladly delete this one.*

Comment: Thank you, especially for the paper.

Comment: The one curious thing - rotations and reflections are either both counted ('fixed' case) or both discounted ('free' case). But I think it makes sense to count reflections, but don't count rotations. If we stay in 2-dimensional space at least, since in 3d reflection is also a kind of rotation of a 2d shape

Comment: @YuriyS Yes. Btw, in OEIS, the reds are counted as one. In your figure above, you are currently missing two (an S-shape and a C-shape) for $n=4$, which gives seven total.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add. I think S-shape should be red too, am I corret?

Comment: @YuriyS Yes. :)